# How to draw a specific color with gpu shader

Tags: python, scripting, opengl

This is a bulid-in shader of gpu module to display a 2D rectangle in viewport,
if you check the color of the rectangle via photoshop/MSpaint or use `gpu.state.active_framebuffer_get().read_color(`,  you will see the color is `#060000`.
The input for the red channel in the script below is `0.005`.
However, when I test for values between `0` and `0.005`, It never shows the color `#050000`.
So how can I draw that rectangle with the color `#050000`?

[image]

```
import bpy
import gpu
from gpu_extras.batch import batch_for_shader

vertices = (
    (100, 100), (300, 100),
    (100, 200), (300, 200))

indices = (
    (0, 1, 2), (2, 1, 3))

shader = gpu.shader.from_builtin('UNIFORM_COLOR')
batch = batch_for_shader(shader, 'TRIS', {"pos": vertices}, indices=indices)


def draw():
    shader.uniform_float("color", (0.005, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0))
    batch.draw(shader)


bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw, (), 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')
```

Comment: I think you can't because floating-point decimal values generally do not have an exact binary representation so it gets capped. so basically you can't.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie They have an exact binary representation, it just has a limited precision and uses a binary rather than decimal numeric system. Some aliens using a ternary numeric system on their planet (because they have 3 fingers), could be very annoyed human decimal system can't express $1 \over 3$ exactly (they would write it as $0.1$).

Answer (score 5):

**Actually you can, see edit below.**

As @Harry McKenzie suggested, you can't. Let me make this plausible by some observations. I changed your script a little to produce all grey tones from *0-1* with a step of *0.001*.

```
import bpy
import gpu
from gpu_extras.batch import batch_for_shader


indices = (
    (0, 1, 2), (2, 1, 3))

shader = gpu.shader.from_builtin('UNIFORM_COLOR')
batch = []
for i in range(1000):
    vertices = (
        (10 + i, 100), (10 + i+1, 100),
        (10 + i, 200), (10 + i+1, 200))
    batch.append(batch_for_shader(shader, 'TRIS', {"pos": vertices}, indices=indices))


pixels = []
for i in range(1000):
    pixels.append(None)
    
    
def draw():
    for i in range(1000):
        c = i * 0.001
        shader.uniform_float("color", (c,c,c, 1.0))
        batch[i].draw(shader)

        pixels[i] = gpu.state.active_framebuffer_get().read_color(10 + i, 100, 1,1, 4, 0, 'FLOAT')

        # warning: prints a lot    
        print("p", i, ":", pixels[i])

bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw, (), 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')
```

Inspecting the prints, you will notice there are "blocks of 4 equal floats":

```
p 0 : Buffer(FLOAT, [[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]]])
p 1 : Buffer(FLOAT, [[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]]])
p 2 : Buffer(FLOAT, [[[0.003921568859368563, 0.003921568859368563, 0.003921568859368563, 1.0]]])
p 3 : Buffer(FLOAT, [[[0.003921568859368563, 0.003921568859368563, 0.003921568859368563, 1.0]]])
p 4 : Buffer(FLOAT, [[[0.003921568859368563, 0.003921568859368563, 0.003921568859368563, 1.0]]])
p 5 : Buffer(FLOAT, [[[0.003921568859368563, 0.003921568859368563, 0.003921568859368563, 1.0]]])
p 6 : Buffer(FLOAT, [[[0.007843137718737125, 0.007843137718737125, 0.007843137718737125, 1.0]]])
p 7 : Buffer(FLOAT, [[[0.007843137718737125, 0.007843137718737125, 0.007843137718737125, 1.0]]])
p 8 : Buffer(FLOAT, [[[0.007843137718737125, 0.007843137718737125, 0.007843137718737125, 1.0]]])
p 9 : Buffer(FLOAT, [[[0.007843137718737125, 0.007843137718737125, 0.007843137718737125, 1.0]]])
p 10 : Buffer(FLOAT, [[[0.011764707043766975, 0.011764707043766975, 0.011764707043766975, 1.0]]])
p 11 : Buffer(FLOAT, [[[0.011764707043766975, 0.011764707043766975, 0.011764707043766975, 1.0]]])
p 12 : Buffer(FLOAT, [[[0.011764707043766975, 0.011764707043766975, 0.011764707043766975, 1.0]]])
p 13 : Buffer(FLOAT, [[[0.011764707043766975, 0.011764707043766975, 0.011764707043766975, 1.0]]])
...
p 987 : Buffer(FLOAT, [[[0.988235354423523, 0.988235354423523, 0.988235354423523, 1.0]]])
p 988 : Buffer(FLOAT, [[[0.988235354423523, 0.988235354423523, 0.988235354423523, 1.0]]])
p 989 : Buffer(FLOAT, [[[0.988235354423523, 0.988235354423523, 0.988235354423523, 1.0]]])
p 990 : Buffer(FLOAT, [[[0.988235354423523, 0.988235354423523, 0.988235354423523, 1.0]]])
p 991 : Buffer(FLOAT, [[[0.9921569228172302, 0.9921569228172302, 0.9921569228172302, 1.0]]])
p 992 : Buffer(FLOAT, [[[0.9921569228172302, 0.9921569228172302, 0.9921569228172302, 1.0]]])
p 993 : Buffer(FLOAT, [[[0.9921569228172302, 0.9921569228172302, 0.9921569228172302, 1.0]]])
p 994 : Buffer(FLOAT, [[[0.9960784912109375, 0.9960784912109375, 0.9960784912109375, 1.0]]])
p 995 : Buffer(FLOAT, [[[0.9960784912109375, 0.9960784912109375, 0.9960784912109375, 1.0]]])
p 996 : Buffer(FLOAT, [[[0.9960784912109375, 0.9960784912109375, 0.9960784912109375, 1.0]]])
p 997 : Buffer(FLOAT, [[[0.9960784912109375, 0.9960784912109375, 0.9960784912109375, 1.0]]])
p 998 : Buffer(FLOAT, [[[0.9960784912109375, 0.9960784912109375, 0.9960784912109375, 1.0]]])
p 999 : Buffer(FLOAT, [[[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]]])
```

or as an image:

[image]

This is because you have to squeeze 1000 values into the R-channel which goes from *#00* to *#FF* and offers place for only 256 values. Thus roughly 4 adjacent float values will fall into one hexadecimal value, because *1000 / 256 = 3.90625*. (The two values at the beginning for *#00* and the end value for *#FF* belong symmetrically together, `p 1000` would also be *1.0*). Thats why sometimes you can see a block of just 3 (missing a 4th) or a 5/3 split instead of 4/4 (e.g. at `p 993/994`). This is because of rounding errors (for the exact conversion formula one would need to know all data types participating when the color values go back and forth, but i did not look into the engine).

(*Edit: choosing 1024 would have made the explanantion easier :)*)

But now you know for sure that:

*{0.000, ... ,0.001}* is mapped to *0.0* which is evaluated as *#00*

*{0.002, ... ,0.005}* is mapped to *0.003921568859368563* which is evaluated as *#06*

and so on...

So, no chance for these guys *#01, #02, #03, #04, #05* :(

**Edit:**

I dug deeper and there actually is a way to get all hex values on screen, but not with the approach above so that observation still holds. But the observation only shows *that* the values get capped, but *why*?

Simplifying the above script to this:

```
import bpy
import gpu
from gpu_extras.batch import batch_for_shader

shader = gpu.shader.from_builtin('UNIFORM_COLOR')

batches = []
indices = ((0, 1, 2), (2, 1, 3))
for i in range(256):
    vertices = ((10 + i, 100), (10 + i+1, 100), (10 + i, 200), (10 + i+1, 200))
    batches.append(batch_for_shader(shader, 'TRIS', {"pos": vertices}, indices=indices))

def draw():
    for i in range(256):
        c = i / 255.0  # come on, all hex values plz
        #shader.uniform_bool("srgbTarget", False)
        shader.uniform_float("color", (c,c,c, 1.0))
        batches[i].draw(shader)

bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw, (), 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')
```

and running it gives a linear looking gradient (*(127,127,127) in the middle*) but with capped values, so there may be a problem within the shader. The shader's implementation is interesting ([source](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/246292f48645673b5742e6689ebd969872372a8c/source/blender/gpu/shaders/gpu_shader_uniform_color_frag.glsl)):

```
#pragma BLENDER_REQUIRE(gpu_shader_colorspace_lib.glsl)

void main()
{
  fragColor = blender_srgb_to_framebuffer_space(color); // huh?
}
```

Looking further one finds the implementation of this function ([source](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/246292f48645673b5742e6689ebd969872372a8c/source/blender/gpu/shaders/gpu_shader_colorspace_lib.glsl)):

```
#ifndef USE_GPU_SHADER_CREATE_INFO
uniform bool srgbTarget = false;
#endif

vec4 blender_srgb_to_framebuffer_space(vec4 in_color)
{
  if (srgbTarget) {
    # this is the very precise version of the common gamma correction
    vec3 c = max(in_color.rgb, vec3(0.0));
    vec3 c1 = c * (1.0 / 12.92);
    vec3 c2 = pow((c + 0.055) * (1.0 / 1.055), vec3(2.4));
    in_color.rgb = mix(c1, c2, step(vec3(0.04045), c));
  }
  return in_color;
}
```

Note the uniform `srgbTarget` which is defaulted to `false`. Setting this uniform explicitly to `false` with `shader.uniform_bool("srgbTarget", False)` should not change anything. But surprise, now the gradient is nonlinear (*(187,187,187) in the middle*)!

[image]

This can't be. Turns out `srgbTarget` for the `UNIFORM_COLOR` shader is set to `true` ([source](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/246292f48645673b5742e6689ebd969872372a8c/source/blender/gpu/shaders/infos/gpu_shader_3D_uniform_color_info.hh#L18)), but this means the gamma correction in `blender_srgb_to_framebuffer_space` takes place before the color value is fed into `FragColor`. And this means the values must be somehow corrected back after that! There is a newer feature in OpenGL where the driver can gamma correct all framebuffers after fragment shaders have been run and there are traces of that in Blender ([source](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/246292f48645673b5742e6689ebd969872372a8c/source/blender/gpu/opengl/gl_framebuffer.cc#L280)), thus i assume its enabled for the default framebuffer. Thus gamma correcting and reverting this correction seems to be the root cause for the numerical issues.

However, one can do offscreen rendering ([source](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/main/doc/python_api/examples/gpu.8.py)) and hope that the driver's gamma correction is not enabled (i have no idea if this can be set). Starting from there and with the other examples, i created this script:

```
import bpy
import gpu
import math
import random
from mathutils import Matrix
from gpu_extras.batch import batch_for_shader

# create the 'UNIFORM COLOR' shader ourself

shader_info = gpu.types.GPUShaderCreateInfo()
shader_info.push_constant('MAT4', "viewProjectionMatrix")
shader_info.push_constant('FLOAT', "color")
shader_info.vertex_in(0, 'VEC3', "position")
shader_info.fragment_out(0, 'VEC4', "FragColor")

shader_info.vertex_source(
    "void main()"
    "{"
    "  gl_Position = viewProjectionMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0f);"
    "}"
)

shader_info.fragment_source(
    "void main()"
    "{"
    "  float c = color / 255.0;"
    "  FragColor = vec4(c, c, c, 1.0);"
    "}"
)

shader = gpu.shader.create_from_info(shader_info)
del shader_info

# create the batches to render each column in the image

batches = []
step = 2 / 255.0
for i in range(256):
    k = i * step - 1.0 - step * 0.5
    coords = [
        (k, -1, 0), (k+step, -1, 0), (k+step, 1, 0),
        (k+step, 1, 0), (k, 1, 0), (k, -1, 0)]
    
    batches.append(batch_for_shader(shader, 'TRIS', {"position": coords}))

# start offscreen rendering

IMAGE_NAME = "all_hex_values"
WIDTH = 256
HEIGHT = 256

offscreen = gpu.types.GPUOffScreen(WIDTH, HEIGHT)

with offscreen.bind():
    fb = gpu.state.active_framebuffer_get()
    fb.clear(color=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0))
    with gpu.matrix.push_pop():
        # reset matrices -> use normalized device coordinates [-1, 1]
        shader.uniform_float("viewProjectionMatrix", Matrix.Identity(4))
        
        for i in range(256):    
            shader.uniform_float("color", i)
            batches[i].draw(shader)

    buffer = fb.read_color(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 4, 0, 'UBYTE')

offscreen.free()

# copy the render result into an blender image

if IMAGE_NAME not in bpy.data.images:
    bpy.data.images.new(IMAGE_NAME, WIDTH, HEIGHT)

image = bpy.data.images[IMAGE_NAME]
image.scale(WIDTH, HEIGHT)

buffer.dimensions = WIDTH * HEIGHT * 4
image.pixels = [v / 255 for v in buffer]
```

Save the image and you got all these precious hex values in its full glory:

[image]

Comment: yes exactly +1 :)

Comment: I made some tests and apparently the implementation underneath uses an 8-bit [minifloat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minifloat). Here's a [calculator](https://observablehq.com/@benaubin/floating-point), if you set `4` as both precision and exponent bits, and then test consecutive numbers `0x0`, `0x1`, `0x2`, `0x3`, `0x4`, `0x5`, `0x6`… You will get `0`, `0.001953125`, `0.00390625`, `0.005859375`, `0.0078125`, `0.009765625`, `0.01171875`, suspiciously similar ;)

Comment: Apparently it uses 3 precision bits (1 sign, 2 mantissa; if there's no sign, then it's just 2 precision bits) and 4 exponent bits, totaling 7 bits (or 6 without a sign), then it skips every other value listed above.

Comment: As user43967 points out in the comment section to his answer, the values listed `0.003921568859368563`, `0.007843137718737125`, `0.011764707043766975`, when multiplied by `255` give `1.000000059138983565`, `2.000000118277966875`, `3.000000296160578625`, so the precision is enough to get those low values. However, it starts failing at `0x9`, which gives one too much: `0.0390625` ×255 = `9.9609375` instead of 9. This is because the exponent increases and from now on some colors will be skipped. Understandable: need 8 bits to describe `0..255` range, and above I just figured it's 6/7 bits…

Answer (score 1):

There is a **lower bound** values of the color (00-FF) except `['0x1', '0x2', '0x3', '0x4', '0x5', '0x7', '0x8', '0xa', '0xe', '0x92', '0x96', '0x99', '0x9b', '0xa1', '0xa3', '0xa5', '0xa8', '0xab', '0xb1', '0xb6', '0xb8', '0xba', '0xbc', '0xbe', '0xc1', '0xc3', '0xe8', '0xf3', '0xfb']`

This means that there are 29 color of a channel that cannot be displayed in this shader. (24389 of 16777216)

I'd appreciate it if someone could solve this problem through use the alpha value or a custom shader to display those missing colors.

```
Hex    Value
0x00 : 0.0
0x01 : -
0x02 : -
0x03 : -
0x04 : -
0x05 : -
0x06 : 0.0015771483886055648
0x07 : -
0x08 : -
0x09 : 0.005520019447430968
0x0a : -
0x0b : 0.009462890680879354
0x0c : 0.013405761215835811
0x0d : 0.017348631285130978
0x0e : -
0x0f : 0.02129150275141001
0x10 : 0.025234374217689037
0x11 : 0.029177243821322918
0x12 : 0.0370629858225584
0x13 : 0.04099433310329915
0x14 : 0.04546292312443257
0x15 : 0.04898468963801861
0x16 : 0.05300186388194561
0x17 : 0.061055721715092666
0x18 : 0.06452127173542978
0x19 : 0.06893400475382805
0x1a : 0.07262223586440086
0x1b : 0.07616695389151573
0x1c : 0.08006047829985619
0x1d : 0.08829088881611825
0x1e : 0.09216826036572458
0x1f : 0.0959075875580311
0x20 : 0.0999157913029194
0x21 : 0.10378383472561838
0x22 : 0.10752426460385324
0x23 : 0.11604240164160728
0x24 : 0.11942188814282419
0x25 : 0.12335999682545663
0x26 : 0.12780576199293137
0x27 : 0.13149937242269516
0x28 : 0.1350933536887169
0x29 : 0.1391696259379387
0x2a : 0.14312943071126938
0x2b : 0.15073328465223312
0x2c : 0.15490704029798508
0x2d : 0.15896772593259811
0x2e : 0.16292332857847214
0x2f : 0.16678082197904587
0x30 : 0.17054661363363266
0x31 : 0.17422639578580856
0x32 : 0.17871292680501938
0x33 : 0.18221714347600937
0x34 : 0.18984784930944443
0x35 : 0.19394680112600327
0x36 : 0.19795342534780502
0x37 : 0.20187317579984665
0x38 : 0.20571088045835495
0x39 : 0.20947109907865524
0x3a : 0.21388676017522812
0x3b : 0.21749045699834824
0x3c : 0.2217286452651024
0x3d : 0.22519230097532272
0x3e : 0.23326962441205978
0x3f : 0.23719196766614914
0x40 : 0.2410418912768364
0x41 : 0.24482300132513046
0x42 : 0.2491515800356865
0x43 : 0.2527943104505539
0x44 : 0.25696931779384613
0x45 : 0.2604866474866867
0x46 : 0.26509262621402746
0x47 : 0.26848720014095306
0x48 : 0.2729371637105942
0x49 : 0.27621997892856603
0x4a : 0.28052739799022675
0x4b : 0.2878845483064652
0x4c : 0.2919911295175553
0x4d : 0.2960308641195297
0x4e : 0.3000065237283707
0x4f : 0.3039207607507706
0x50 : 0.3077761381864548
0x51 : 0.31157501041889196
0x52 : 0.3153195530176163
0x53 : 0.31992693245410925
0x54 : 0.32355655729770666
0x55 : 0.32713808119297033
0x56 : 0.33155001699924475
0x57 : 0.33502940833568573
0x58 : 0.33931849896907806
0x59 : 0.3431235700845719
0x5a : 0.3468784242868424
0x5b : 0.3550512939691544
0x5c : 0.3590535074472428
0x5d : 0.3630023151636124
0x5e : 0.36689950525760656
0x5f : 0.37074701488018036
0x60 : 0.37454645335674286
0x61 : 0.37829931080341345
0x62 : 0.38274364173412323
0x63 : 0.38639952242374426
0x64 : 0.3900134414434433
0x65 : 0.3942967206239701
0x66 : 0.39782290160655975
0x67 : 0.4020042270421982
0x68 : 0.40613268315792084
0x69 : 0.40953396260738373
0x6a : 0.4135699421167374
0x6b : 0.41755788028240204
0x6c : 0.4214992970228195
0x6d : 0.4253955036401749
0x6e : 0.42924802005290985
0x6f : 0.43305812776088715
0x70 : 0.43745122849941254
0x71 : 0.4454674571752548
0x72 : 0.4491072744131088
0x73 : 0.45271067321300507
0x74 : 0.4568699449300766
0x75 : 0.4609823673963547
0x76 : 0.46447114646434784
0x77 : 0.46850042045116425
0x78 : 0.4724867194890976
0x79 : 0.47643129527568817
0x7a : 0.48033522069454193
0x7b : 0.48419974744319916
0x7c : 0.4880258589982987
0x7d : 0.49235282838344574
0x7e : 0.49610008299350744
0x7f : 0.49981193244457245
0x80 : 0.504012018442154
0x81 : 0.5081683099269867
0x82 : 0.511770099401474
0x83 : 0.5153402388095857
0x84 : 0.5193823873996736
0x85 : 0.5233851373195648
0x86 : 0.5273495018482209
0x87 : 0.5312764942646028
0x88 : 0.5351668894290925
0x89 : 0.5390217006206512
0x8a : 0.5428418219089509
0x8b : 0.5470990836620331
0x8c : 0.5513145625591278
0x8d : 0.5550274550914764
0x8e : 0.5587090551853181
0x8f : 0.5623598992824554
0x90 : 0.5668815076351166
0x91 : 0.5704658329486848
0x92 : -
0x93 : 0.5784274041652679
0x94 : 0.5823560655117035
0x95 : 0.586251050233841
0x96 : -
0x97 : 0.5939435064792634
0x98 : 0.5981624424457551
0x99 : -
0x9a : 0.6056618392467499
0x9b : -
0x9c : 0.6138570606708528
0x9d : 0.6179024875164032
0x9e : 0.6219141185283661
0x9f : 0.6250996291637421
0xa0 : 0.6329734027385712
0xa1 : -
0xa2 : 0.6368633806705476
0xa3 : -
0xa4 : 0.6453152596950531
0xa5 : -
0xa6 : 0.652876764535904
0xa7 : 0.6610659658908845
0xa8 : -
0xa9 : 0.6647453010082245
0xaa : 0.6683984696865082
0xab : -
0xac : 0.676345854997635
0xad : 0.6806304156780243
0xae : 0.6883957087993622
0xaf : 0.6918881237506868
0xb0 : 0.6960491836071014
0xb1 : -
0xb2 : 0.7001781165599823
0xb3 : 0.7035949528217317
0xb4 : 0.7076669037342073
0xb5 : 0.7117086350917816
0xb6 : -
0xb7 : 0.719703882932663
0xb8 : -
0xb9 : 0.7275852262973787
0xba : -
0xbb : 0.7353568971157074
0xbc : -
0xbd : 0.7428644001483918
0xbe : -
0xbf : 0.7510570585727693
0xc0 : 0.7547992765903474
0xc1 : -
0xc2 : 0.7628252804279329
0xc3 : -
0xc4 : 0.770742565393448
0xc5 : 0.7743611037731171
0xc6 : 0.7785550057888031
0xc7 : 0.782126396894455
0xc8 : 0.7862661778926849
0xc9 : 0.7903777062892914
0xca : 0.7938797175884247
0xcb : 0.7979399859905243
0xcc : 0.801973432302475
0xcd : 0.8059804737567903
0xce : 0.8099614083766937
0xcf : 0.8133535087108612
0xd0 : 0.8178474605083466
0xd1 : 0.8211969435214997
0xd2 : 0.82563516497612
0xd3 : 0.8294930160045624
0xd4 : 0.8333274424076081
0xd5 : 0.8371388614177704
0xd6 : 0.8409275710582733
0xd7 : 0.8452303111553192
0xd8 : 0.8489717543125154
0xd9 : 0.852691560983658
0xda : 0.8569168746471405
0xdb : 0.8611148893833162
0xdc : 0.8647662699222566
0xdd : 0.868397444486618
0xde : 0.8725230395793915
0xdf : 0.8766230642795564
0xe0 : 0.8806980550289154
0xe1 : 0.884243279695511
0xe2 : 0.8882721960544587
0xe3 : 0.8917779624462128
0xe4 : 0.8957622945308685
0xe5 : 0.8997233808040619
0xe6 : 0.9036616384983064
0xe7 : 0.9075773656368256
0xe8 : -
0xe9 : 0.9114709198474885
0xea : 0.9153425991535188
0xeb : 0.9196726381778718
0xec : 0.9234990179538728
0xed : 0.9277788698673249
0xee : 0.9315613806247712
0xef : 0.9353236258029939
0xf0 : 0.9427888095378876
0xf1 : 0.9474151432514192
0xf2 : 0.9510947763919831
0xf3 : -
0xf4 : 0.9547555744647981
0xf5 : 0.9588519632816316
0xf6 : 0.9629253447055818
0xf7 : 0.9665270149707795
0xf8 : 0.9705578386783601
0xf9 : 0.9745666086673738
0xfa : 0.9825190603733064
0xfb : -
0xfc : 0.9860263168811799
0xfd : 0.9903871715068817
0xfe : 0.9938577711582185
0xff : 0.9981732666492463
```

Comment: In fact, I used 0.000000...001 step to test more than trillion of values, and that table is the result, there is no way to display some colors in that shader :(

Comment: @X Y, i updated my answer, hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Although you can't get 0.001 steps, the steps should be 1/255 = 0.0039...  Try 1/255*5=0.0196..., or just use 5.0/255.0 to get 5 in the red channel.

This provides a simple test.  Replace pixels in bpy image with X/255.0, then you can just hover over the images and see the RGB values, which are all int8 and not float.

```
show_image(bpy_image):
    pixels = np.multiply(bpy_image.pixels, 255)
    array = np.array(pixels, dtype=np.uint8)
    array = np.reshape(array, (bpy_image.size[1], bpy_image.size[0], 4))
    print(np.shape(array))
    img = Image.fromarray(array)
    imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not true, as stated by both OP and taiyo

Comment: That isn't what Taiyo showed.  He actually showed that 0.001 was smaller than one step.  As expected, you see 0 for the first 2 steps.  Then you see: 1 (0.0039...) for the next 4 steps, 2 for the next 4 steps (0.0078...) and so on.  If he is using the shader and it continues to work that way, you should see the value for 5 (0.0195...) in some of the other steps.  If the values are really skipped like X Y indicates, that is a different issue.  Based on Taiyo's test, all 256 values should be possible.

Comment: You're correct, I was so focused on very low precision that I missed the first value `0.003921568859368563` multiplied by 255 gives `1.000000059138983565`. However it still doesn't solve the question, and setting the value to `1/255` (`1/256` would be incorrect) doesn't allow to set the color to `0x01`…

Comment: Little but important typo: it should be _0.0039..._ not _0.039..._

Comment: 255 is actually correct -- see https://docs.blender.org/api/current/mathutils.html#mathutils.Color

Comment: @user43967 turns out it _is_ a different issue and the values are possible. I edited my answer.